# How to use the updated value in redux store immediately after the action is dispatched in react js functional components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

need updated value of "props.error" after getActionUser Action is dispatched in HandleSignIn function.
the code is getting executed with old value of "props.error" even it is used after action got dispatched and updated the redux store.

Please help me get the updated value just after the action got dispatched

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getActiveUser} from "../../redux-store/actions/login";

const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setdisable(true);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      setdisable(false)
    },500);

    if(validateForm()){

      const user = { 'email': email, 'password': password };
      await props.getActiveUser(user);

      // need to use the updated value of (error) after getActiveUser is dispatched
      if(props.error){
       alert(props.error);
      }
      else{
      alert(props.error)
      }
   }

  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <GridContainer justify="center">

        <GridItem xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
        <Snackbar
                      place="tr"
                      color="warning"
                      icon={AddAlert}
                      message="Invalid Credentials"
                      open={tl}
                      // closeNotification={() => setTL(false)}
                      // close
                    />
          <form>
            <Card login className={classes[cardAnimaton]}>

                <CardHeader
                className={`${classes.cardHeader} ${classes.textCenter}`}
                /*color=""*/
                style={{margin: '0'}}
              >
{/*                <h4 className={classes.cardTitle}>Log in</h4>
                <div className={classes.socialLine}>
                  {[
                    "fab fa-facebook-square",
                    "fab fa-twitter",
                    "fab fa-google-plus"
                  ].map((prop, key) => {
                    return (
                      <Button
                        color="transparent"
                        justIcon
                        key={key}
                        className={classes.customButtonClass}
                      >
                        <i className={prop} />
                      </Button>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>*/}
                <img src={Logo} alt="Paxafe" style={{height: '26px', marginTop: '1.5rem'}}/>
              </CardHeader>


              <CardBody>
                <CustomInput
                  labelText="Email..."
                  id="email"
                  formControlProps={{
                    fullWidth: true
                  }}
                  inputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Email className={classes.inputAdornmentIcon} />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    onChange: (e) => {
                      setEmail(e.target.value);
                    }
                  }}
                  onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
                {emailError?(<p style={{color:'#e53935',marginTop:'-15px',position:'absolute'}}>{emailError}</p>):('')}
                <CustomInput
                  labelText="Password"
                  id="password"
                  formControlProps={{
                    fullWidth: true
                  }}
                  inputProps={{
                    endAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Icon className={classes.inputAdornmentIcon}>
                          lock_outline
                        </Icon>
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    type: "password",
                    autoComplete: "off",
                    onChange: (e) => {
                      setPassword(e.target.value);
                    }
                  }}

                />
                  {passwordError?(<p style={{color:'#e53935',marginTop:'-15px',position:'absolute'}}>{passwordError}</p>):('')}
              </CardBody>
              <CardFooter className={classes.justifyContentCenter}>
                <Button color="info" size="lg" block onClick={handleSignIn} type='submit' disabled={disable}>
                  Login
                </Button>

              </CardFooter>
            </Card>
          </form>
        </GridItem>
      </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return {
    error:state.login.error
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{getActiveUser})(Login));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`props` is object and is passed as argument to `handleSignIn` component. It will be updated with `error` but only on next render.

But you can return `error` from `getActiveUser` action creator like below

```
const getActiveUser = user => dispatch => {
    /* do work */
    dispatch ({type: 'ERROR', error });
    return error;
}
```

And you can consume returned value in component immedeately

```
const error = await props.getActiveUser (user)
```

Comment: its working.  but why can't i get the updated redux value. and why to use redux if dont get the value

Comment: The idea of React component is that it

1. Gets props
2. Render something on screen
3. If props updated, it rerenders
And so on
So porps are static when you're inside component code. 
Props will be updated and component rerenders. React will merge updates from component and present smooth interface to user. 
When props are static it is easier to develop component, than if props are sporadically change